# Custom Logout and Drupal Logout

Tags: users

we are implementing a custom login (based on an auth cookie given by a third party authentication service). When the cookie arrives, we trigger the drupal user_login.
When the user logs out (via a custom box, NOT drupal logout link), we trigger the user_logout.

The problem is: if you clear the cookie auth, you remain logged on drupal.
What hook can we implement to trigger the logout anytime the cookie auth disappear?

Comment: *["If the question is about code you wrote, for which you want to write better code, or you want to understand why it doesn't work, show the code you are using, or the part of the code that is relevant for the question. Questions that are substantially about code, where the code is not shown, are possibly closed."](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no hook for 3rd party cookie removal, and there cannot be. You need to bootstrap Drupal and call [`user_logout()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.pages.inc/function/user_logout/7).

You could also use [`hook_boot()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_boot/7) to test for the cookie and logout if it's not there, but it is a **bad idea** - it may seriously hurt your performance and will not play nice with external caches.